# Is there a finite number of solutions to $\mathrm{Re}(a^n)+\mathrm{Im}(a^n)=b^n$, where $a$ is a Gaussian integer and $b \in \Bbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, arithmetic

Let $$E_n=\{(x,y,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^*\times \mathbb{Z}^*\times \mathbb{Z}^* ~|~ \gcd(x,y,b)=1 ~ \mathrm{and}~\mathrm{Re}((x+iy)^n)+\mathrm{Im}((x+iy)^n)=b^n \}$$

For $n \geq 3$, is $E_n$ finite or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or is $E_n$ empty? ... ;)

Comment: For example, for $n=4$, it's not empty: if $a=3+2i$, $a^4=(3+2i)^4=-119+120i$. So, $\mathrm{Re}(a^4)+\mathrm{Im}(a^4)=1^4$ ;)

Comment: Sorry, $\Re(a^n)$, not $\Re(a)^n$. I read that quickly and thought someone had put you on FLT for some reason.